# Changing colour for geom_line in ggplot2 independently from group colour

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have the following aggregated data with means and confidence intervals, computed using SummarySEwithin. I have used this to generate the plot below.

[image: Data set]

The code for the plot is as follows:

```
ggplot(df_forplot, aes(x=Phase, y=criterion, colour=Phase)) +
 geom_line(aes(x=Phase, y=criterion, group=1))+geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=criterion-ci, ymax= criterion+ci),width=.1) +
    scale_colour_manual(values= c("#3399FF", "#FF3366"))+
      theme(legend.position = "none")+ mytheme
```

I want to change the line colour to black. How do I achieve this?

[image: Current Plot]

Comment: `geom_line(aes(x=Phase, y=criterion, group=1), colour = "black") +`

Answer (score 0):

As Carl points out above, if you want to change a feature (say, a color) in a plot layer to a fixed value (so it does not depend on data), you need to specify it outside of `aes(...)`. I have added `, colour="black"` fragment in a second line of the code snippet below.

Try this code:

```
ggplot(df_forplot, aes(x=Phase, y=criterion, colour=Phase)) +
 geom_line(aes(x=Phase, y=criterion, group=1), colour="black")+geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=criterion-ci, ymax= criterion+ci),width=.1) +
    scale_colour_manual(values= c("#3399FF", "#FF3366"))+
      theme(legend.position = "none")+ mytheme
```

Comment: Please suggest the original commenter posts their comment as an answer.  Simply posting (a slightly modified) version of their comment as an answer could be regarded as plagiarism.

Comment: @Limey (1) It certainly cannot be regarded as plagiarism since it was properly attributed. (2) Moving useful information from the comments to an answer is permitted here, but I agree that common *etiquette* here is to ask the original commenter to convert it to an answer if found useful. I often will create a community-wiki answer and offer to remove it if the OP wants to provide an answer. This avoids any possibility of misconstruing what can be a helpful answer.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines that explaining *why* Carl's snippet actually works is adding valuable information that might be useful for others, too.